# How to make two side by side Qt Windows sticky and act like a single window?

Tags: qt, widget, drag

I am trying to implement a scenario where two Qt windows will be placed side by side and they will be kind of sticky to each other. By dragging one of them, the other also gets dragged. Even when doing an alt-tab they should behave like a single window.

Any help or pointer will be extremely helpful.

-Soumya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe sounds like it's a good fit for a "docking" scenario.  You're probably most familiar with docking from toolbars; where you can either float a toolbar on its own or stick it to any edge of an app's window.  But Qt has a more generalized mechanism:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-dockwidgets-example.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html

It won't be a case where multiple top level windows are moved around in sync with their own title bars and such.  The top-level windows will be merged into a single containing window when they need to get "sticky".  But IMO this is more elegant for almost any situation, and provides the properties you seem to be seeking.

Comment: This seems like a possible implementation. Will definitely try this route. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Install a event filter on the tracked window with [`QObject::installEventFilter()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) and filter on [`QEvent::Move`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum)

You can then change the position of tracking window whenever your filter is called with that event type.

Comment: Technically possible, but don't you think the OP should consider `QDockWidget` instead of going ahead with something so quirky?

Comment: I don't think QDockWidget is appropriate. It's a means of grouping widgets, yes, but you will need to do something "quirky" in order to prevent them from being *un*-grouped! If you try to move one widget it will un-dock instead of pushing its sticky neighbour around.

Comment: I've seen very little effective implementation of the approach.  WinAmp did some interesting stickiness...but they were trying to optimize screen real-estate as opposed to grouping the media player and playlist and EQ into a bounding rectangle...since it could be "on top" a lot and not the user's focus.  So if the question is not phrased as "I don't want to use QDockWidget because..." I'd lean toward assuming lack of awareness of QDockWidget!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to keep two windows anchored: when the user moves a window, the other follows, keeping its relative position to the moved one.

It is a bit of a hack, because it assumes that the event [`QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress) is sent when the user left clicks on the title bar, holding it pressed while he moves the window, and releasing it at the end, so that [`QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease) is sent.

The idea is to use the [`QWidget::moveEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#moveEvent) event handler of each window to update the geometry of the other, using [`QWidget::setGeometry`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGeometry-1).

But the documentation states that:

`Calling setGeometry() inside resizeEvent() or moveEvent() can lead to infinite recursion.`

So I needed to prevent the `moveEvent` handler of the windows which was not moved directly by the user, to update the geometry of the other.

I achieved this with result via [`QObject::installEventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter), intercepting the summentioned events.

When the user clicks on the title bar of `WindowOne` to start a move operation, `WindowOne::eventFilter` catches its `QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress` and sets the public attribute `WindowTwo::skipevent_two` to `true`.

While the user is moving `WindowOne`, `WindowTwo::moveEvent` is called upon the `setGeometry` operation, performed on `WindowTwo` from `WindowOne::moveEvent`.

`WindowTwo::moveEvent` checks `WindowTwo::skipevent_two`, and if it is `true`, returns without performing a `setGeometry` operation on `WindowOne` which would cause infinite recursion.

As soon as the user releases the left mouse button, ending the window move operation, `WindowOne::eventFilter` catches `QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease` and sets back  the public attribute `WindowTwo::skipevent_two` to `false`.

The same actions are performed if the user clicks the titlebar of `WindowTwo`, this time causing `WindowOne::skipevent_one` attribute to be set to `true` and preventing `WindowOne::moveEvent` to perform any `setGeometry` operation on `WindowTwo`.

I believe this solution is far from being clean and usable. Some problems:

- I am not sure when and why `QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease` and `QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease` are dispatched, apart from the case considered above.
- When/if one window is resized without user interaction or without the proper mouse clicks from the user, probably everything will go the infinite recursion way.
- There is no guarantee that those mouse events will be dispatched the same way in the future.
- Free space for more...

Proof of concept:
https://github.com/Shub77/DockedWindows